# Sidebar at bottom of page when using pagination in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

We have a page in our wordpress based website that has the sidebar showing up at the bottom of the page. This is the only page on the site where we use the `<!--nextpage-->` code to make it use the native wordpress pagination.

The first page of the two is the one that has the problem: http://www.yourwhiteknight.com/testimonials/

If you look at the second page it is fine: http://www.yourwhiteknight.com/testimonials/2/

I have been searching my code and the content for extra divs that may have caused this to appear out of place but can not find them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 0):

If they are separate template files you can remove sidebar(); from the markup. Your site also seems to have malware on it. See the developer tools (f12) and console tab.

Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.yourwhiteknight.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: As far as I know they are not separate template pages and we want the sidebar to show up on the side.

Comment: Of course, my bad. But I can't do anything without being inside so start with the 2 JavaScript errors. Upon further examination I found portfolioSlideshowOptions is an underlying problem. Are you aware of that? Is there anything unique within that page's sidebar that the working sidebar doesn't have?

Comment: No, the sidebar on http://www.yourwhiteknight.com/testimonials/ and http://www.yourwhiteknight.com/testimonials/2/ are exactly the same. The only difference is that when you look at the code the sidebar on the first page appears inside the .postwrap div and on the second page it is outside. I checked the code of the content that the client put into the page and there are no closing divs that may be screwing it up. I have no idea what the JS errors are or how to fix them. Would love help with that too.

Comment: First things first. Have you disabled plugins one by one to rule them out? We know that portfolioSlideshowOptions is causing issues so maybe start with that?

Comment: I have deactivated all the plugins and tested but the sidebar still shows on the bottom. They are reactivated now so my client doesn't loose any functionality. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I tried to use a newer version of JQuery with the portFolioSlideshowOptions but it just broke the plugin.

Comment: Just saw your post. WP 3.5.2

Comment: I see that both testimonial page's sidebars are messed up now? I really can't trouble shoot it from the front end. Can you talk to the theme dev or upgrade the theme? Might be time anyways.